# Adding an HTML Data attribute that increases in value

Tags: jquery

I need to add an HTML Data attribute to each new parent element on a search results page. This Data attribute needs to begin with a value of 1 and then increase according to the number of parent elements there are.

Example:

```
<div class="hello" data-sort="1"></div>
<div class="hello" data-sort="2"></div>
<div class="hello" data-sort="3"></div>
<div class="hello" data-sort="4"></div>
ect...
```

Looking to solve this with jQuery. Couldn't figure out myself, any assistance would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```js
var $hello = $('.hello');
for(var i = 0; i < $hello.length; i++){
  $hello.attr('data-sort', i +1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution:

```
$("div").each(function(index){
    $(this).attr("data-sort", index);
});
```

`$("div")` can be modified to select whatever you mean by "parent" elements.

Answer (score 0):

You would go through each class (`hello` in this case) and use an incrementing variable (note it starts at zero):

```
$( ".hello" ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).attr("data-sort", index + 1 );
});
```